# python socket related question

Tags: python, sockets

im totally new to socket programming in python. i was read some tutorial and manual, but i didn't found what i want to make python related socket script in manual or tutorial.

i want to make socket script which can send some info to server and also receive some info from server. For example, i want to send my login information to server, and want to receive result reply from server.

but i have no idea..how to send my login  information(id and password) to server.

i was captured with wireshark, some process to send login info to server.

and i was found port number is 5300 and server ip is 58.225.56.152

and i was send id is 'aaaaaaa' and password 'bbbbbbb' and i was received

'USER NOT FOUND' result from server.

how can i make this kind of process with python socket ?

if anyone help me some reference or some example or anything help much appreciate!

```
0000   00 50 56 f2 c8 cc 00 0c 29 a8 f8 c0 08 00 45 00  .PV.....).....E.
0010   00 e2 2a 19 40 00 80 06 d0 55 c0 a8 cb 85 3a e1  ..*.@....U....:.
0020   38 98 05 f3 15 9a b9 86 62 7b 0d ab 0f ba 50 18  8.......b{....P.
0030   fa f0 26 14 00 00 50 54 3f 09 a2 91 7f 13 00 00  ..&...PT?.......
0040   00 1f 14 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  ................
0050   61 61 61 61 61 61 61 50 54 3f 09 a2 91 7f 8b 00  aaaaaaaPT?......
0060   00 00 1f 15 00 08 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 61 61 61  .............aaa
0070   61 61 61 61 07 00 00 00 62 62 62 62 62 62 62 01  aaaa....bbbbbbb.
0080   00 00 00 31 02 00 00 00 4b 52 0f 00 00 00 31 39  ...1....KR....19
0090   32 2e 31 36 38 2e 32 30 33 2e 31 33 33 30 00 00  2.168.203.1330..
00a0   00 4d 69 63 72 6f 73 6f 66 74 20 57 69 6e 64 6f  .Microsoft Windo
00b0   77 73 20 58 50 20 50 72 6f 66 65 73 73 69 6f 6e  ws XP Profession
00c0   61 6c 20 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 20 50 61 63 6b 20  al Service Pack 
00d0   32 14 00 00 00 31 30 30 31 33 30 30 35 33 31 35  2....10013005315
00e0   37 38 33 37 32 30 31 32 33 03 00 00 00 34 37 30  783720123....470

0000   00 0c 29 a8 f8 c0 00 50 56 f2 c8 cc 08 00 45 00  ..)....PV.....E.
0010   00 28 ae 37 00 00 80 06 8c f1 3a e1 38 98 c0 a8  .(.7......:.8...
0020   cb 85 15 9a 05 f3 0d ab 0f ba b9 86 63 35 50 10  ............c5P.
0030   fa f0 5f 8e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              .._.........

0000   00 0c 29 a8 f8 c0 00 50 56 f2 c8 cc 08 00 45 00  ..)....PV.....E.
0010   00 4c ae 38 00 00 80 06 8c cc 3a e1 38 98 c0 a8  .L.8......:.8...
0020   cb 85 15 9a 05 f3 0d ab 0f ba b9 86 63 35 50 18  ............c5P.
0030   fa f0 3e 75 00 00 50 54 3f 09 a2 91 7f 16 00 00  ..>u..PT?.......
0040   00 1f 18 00 01 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 55 73 65 72  ............User
0050   20 4e 6f 74 20 46 6f 75 6e 64                     Not Found
```

Comment: It seems to be protocol-related rather than Python/socket-related. What service do you want to connect to?

Comment: Hi,this is messenger service.. and i think 5300 port used for verification about user authority. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A Python library to connect to MSN Messenger service:

http://blitiri.com.ar/p/msnlib/

(Disclaimer: never used this myself.)

Comment: As I said, I haven't used this library myself, but it seems to contain a working Messenger client in Python; maybe that makes a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

socket is an endpoint which you could send and receive data with it. To access sockets in python, you could use socket module.

Socket is almost the lowest level module that you could implement different protocols with. for example if you want to send http requests and receive http response to/from a server as you mentioned above, you can use different modules like `requests` , `urllib` , `httplib` . but all of them are built using socket module.

Now you should create a socket for server and one for client. One way is to make server sockets job to listen for incomming connections and client socket is to make requests to that listener. After the connection is established another socket will be created in the server side and will send and receive data to/from client socket.

```
#client side
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('server ip address',server port number to which you want to connect))
client_socket.send('hi')
client_socket.recv(4096)
client_socket.close()


#server side
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('server ip address',server port number))
server_socket.listen(0)
server_new_socket,ip_address = server_socket.accept()
server_new_socket.send('connection established')
server_new_socket.recv(4096)
server_new_socket.close()
```

Actually you could modify it to be able to send and receive as many as data that you want